# convert byte array to java.sql.Clob

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

**Is there any way to convert a byte array into java.sql.Clob ?**

I am having this type of issue...

**`getHibernateTemplate().save(object)`**

Where object is having a field `private Clob docData;` and the similar is mapped into oracle table as `CLOB`

This `docData clob` is getting formed from somewhere in my java code like `Hibernate.createClob(someString)`

I tried to save it with `type="clob"` but getting `cann't cast com.sun.proxy$Proxy124 to oracle.sql.CLOB`. I have tried many ways to remove this Proxy but finally failed.

So I have decided to go like `byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(docData.getCharacterStream());` / `byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(docData.getAsciiStream())` and saving it as `type="binary"` but I am getting `Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column`.

So now I want to create as a Clob from byte[].

Any help welcome.

**Note** earlier I was using Hibernate 3.3 and it was working fine without any such byte array conversion and etc...now I have upgraded to Hibernate 3.6.10 and getting this issue.

Comment: Why when you have a character/ascii stream do you want to convert it to binary and then convert it back? Why not just use the original character stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, issue is resolved. I kept the java data type as 'Clob' only and made the hibernate mapping like `type="string"`. Issue got resolved since my digital sign data does not contain more than 2 MB (that java string max supports).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this method to create Blobs:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.NonContextualLobCreator.NonContextualLobCreator.INSTANCE.createBlob( buffer )
```

where buffer is an array of bytes.

There are 2 similar methods for creating CLOBs:

```
NonContextualLobCreator.INSTANCE.createClob( reader, length )
NonContextualLobCreator.INSTANCE.createClob( string )
```

Pick the one that fits better with your data.

Comment: questions :
1. your first one is for creating blob. I dont need this.
2. is reader byte[] type ? and what should be length ?
3. are you suggesting convert byte array to string ?

Comment: Ok you can forget about 1. In your code you're already using `docData.getCharacterStream()` which seems to return a reader so you can either use it or convert to String. Your call.

Comment: I think I am the most unfortunate guy.... I am using `Clob clob  = org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.NonContextualLobCreator.INSTANCE.createClob( new String(IOUtils.toString(docData.getCharacterStream())))` still its type is ClobProxy ....please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says

> cann't cast com.sun.proxy$Proxy124 to **oracle.sql.CLOB**

In the rest of your text you are referring to `java.sql.Clob` Check your imports, you might be using the clob from the oracle.sql package instead of the java.sql package somewhere.